# ASP.NET website 'Publish' vs Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

if i decide to use the 'publish' option for my ASP.NET website, instead of a Web Deployment Project, can i do custom msbuild things? Or do i need to stick with WDP's if i want to do custom msbuild stuff during compile/deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think of the publish option as a part of the VS.NET toolset for developers to use to publish web sites on dev machines.  It isn't really built to be a real deployment.

If you need custom actions, a Web Deployment Project would be more suited to a real deployment that multiple people other than the developer run regularly and that you want created with each build.

I would also look at three other options:

- **PowerShell:** A good way to **script** against IIS, set up websites, etc.  You can even build cmdlets from OO code (like C#) that your script can call.  Many professional IT firms use it to deploy big web sites.
- **MSDeploy:** A new **deployment tool** for websites that can replicate a vroot over several servers.  Very good for having your golden image and then blasting it out to various places.
- **C# application:** If you are a more **advanced developer**, you can always write your own application that xcopies files (via Process) and uses WMI to configure IIS.  Harder, but you have complete control.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use custom MSBuild options. In fact, you can execute MSBuild on a sln file configured to publish as a website, and then copy the precompiled website files to a webserver. We do that internally using Cruise Control.net from Thoughtworks.

The sln file contains info about where the precompiled website will be located:

```
Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/PrecompiledWeb"
Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\Web\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "..\..\PrecompiledWeb\"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "true"
Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't use publish to deploy our web projects, but we used to use Web Deployment Projects.  When we switched to Visual Studio 2008, we ran into a bunch of problems with them, so we got rid of them.

What I can tell you is that we were able to replace the WDP functionality we were using with aspnet_merge.exe.  We use a combination of msbuild and aspnet_merge.exe in a script to get our deployments done.

Comment: Wow.  I hadn't even heard of aspnet_merge until you mentioned it.  Here are the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can customize the Publish task through the _CopyWebApplication MSBuild target. Or you can at least create a batch file that will call that target, which you can customize.

More details [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1063636.aspx) and [here](http://www.driebier.net/post/Using-MSBuild-to-deploy-visual-studio-2005-web-applications-(2).aspx).